# Stop sending rtp when muted

Tags: rtp, pjsip

In the current implementation of pjsip with VAD disabled, it sends frames of zero bytes when mic is muted.  As the VAD flag is codec as well as platform dependent, we cannot rely on that.

What I am looking for is a pjmedia callback just before sending out any RTP packet.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

[pjmedia_stream_pause](http://www.pjsip.org/pjmedia/docs/html/group__PJMED__STRM.htm#ga996ec5e721afbdb6a5be0937b8e26b95) is the solution.